Setup SKU Number on Supermicro
We have a few Systems which are build with Super Chassis and different combinations of Supermicro boards.
Checking the BIOS information via dmidecode -t 1 a lot of information is labeled with To be filled by O.E.M, which not has happened at either of the O.E.M.s which we ordered from.
From the order paper, I am able to receive all the information.
How can I update the information? I am able to connect via ipmitool as well via BMC web console.
Example of the dmidecode command:
Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
        Manufacturer: Supermicro
        Product Name: Super Server
        Version: 0123456789
        Serial Number: 0123456789
        UUID: XXX
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
        Family: To be filled by O.E.M.

